# Bottom border on thead overlaps border in tbody tr with collapse border in table

Tags: html, css

I'm using a table in HTML and I wanted to set a bit of style.
I added a `bottom-border` to the `thead` of my table and there is an active class for `tbody tr` which adds a border.

However, the `bottom-border` of the `thead` overlaps the `border-top` of the active class.

It's because of the collapse border, but I need it because the hover on `tbody tr` does not work properly. Indeed, it adds gaps between each columns.

How could I solve this ?

Here is the code:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  cursor: default;
}

table thead {
  border-bottom: 2px solid;
  text-align: center;
}

table thead th {
  font-weight: normal;
}

table th,
table td {
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

table tbody tr:hover {
  background-color: grey;
}

table tbody tr.active {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Column1</th>
      <th>Column2</th>
      <th>Column3</th>
      <th>Column4</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="active">
      <td>A</td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>C</td>
      <td>D</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>E</td>
      <td>F</td>
      <td>G</td>
      <td>H</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found the trick. I add a `:before` to the `tbody` and a `box-shadow` instead of `border-bottom` for the `thead`.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  cursor: default;
}

table thead {
  box-shadow: 0 2px grey;
  text-align: center;
}

table thead th {
  font-weight: normal;
}

table th,
table td {
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

table tbody tr:hover {
  background-color: grey;
}

table tbody tr.active {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

table tbody:before {
  line-height: 0px;
  content: "\200C";
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Column1</th>
      <th>Column2</th>
      <th>Column3</th>
      <th>Column4</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="active">
      <td>A</td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>C</td>
      <td>D</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>E</td>
      <td>F</td>
      <td>G</td>
      <td>H</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```